# PySpark: Summing more columns with Dinamic names

Tags: pyspark, sum

I have DF like this:

```
+------+------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+

|  A .....|.. B ..|2019-01-31|2019-02-28|2019-03-31|2019-04-30|2019-05-31|

+------+------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+

|11125 |SL15|  15.0    |   12.0   |    1.0   |    0.0   |    0.0   |

|20047 |SL20|   7.0    |   13.0   |    1.0   |    0.0   |    0.0   |

|35858 |SL25|   8.0    |    0.0   |    1.0   |    0.0   |    0.0   |
```

I am creating a calculated field like new field, which sum up columns 3 to 7(5 month).
My problem is that columns have dynamic names.
This month column names are different that next month, but are always located on exact positions. (secured in flow, correct column which must be on position 3 will on position 3 next month, only names are changing).

That means every month I will sum up columns from 3 to 7.

example
If I assign first variable like this colH1 = F.col("2019-01-31") and second like this colH2 = F.col("2019-02-28"), I can do mathematical operations between them.
New calculated column is Like this: df = df.withColumn('new_column',((colH1) + (colH2)))

What need to change is mentioned assignment of colH1 = F.col("2019-01-31") as ("2019-01-31") is fix name of the column on position 3 in DF this month, but name will change next month. I need calculation with “Position3”.

I cannot use df.select, as this operation just pick the exact  column, but then I am unable to join it back to original DF - no unique keys for joining

I hope, that this explains my needs, but not find a solution to such a case.

Answer (score 0):

get the column name based on column index and store into variable. you can get the column name based on column index by below code.

`df.columns(index)`

pass the variable in below code.

`df = df.withColumn('new_column',((var1) + (var2)))`